# Aggregating and Bucketing in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which needs to be bucketed and then aggregated based on a set of break points given as input.
Lets say the data set is:

```
> x.df
     x1      x2
1  84.05370  2
2  39.61822  5
3  97.58997  6
4  78.28167  6
5  14.52273  9
6  17.18028  3
7  61.31518  9
8  97.63569  7
9  40.52498  4
10 13.21434  3
```

and the break points as inputs are

```
breaks = c(3,6)
```

I need to find the sum of x1 where x2 lies in these buckets (<=3, 3-6, >6). I looked at aggregate() and cut() functions but haven't been able to put them together to achieve the result in an elegant way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add categories to your breaks. As you can see, values lower/greater than minimum and maximum of breaks are set to `NA`. Therefore I append minimum and maximum values (`-Inf` and `Inf`).

```
cut(1:9, c(3,6))
[1] <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  (3,6] (3,6] (3,6] <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
Levels: (3,6]
```

Also - `aggregate` function accepts `list` to make groups, so you must provide your breaks as a list.

```
# add categories to breaks
breaks <- c(-Inf,3,6,Inf)

# aggregate
aggregate(x.df$x1, by=list(cut(x.df$x2, breaks)), FUN=sum)
```